# How to convert and Android html view to binary data?

Tags: java, android, html, bluetooth, binary

I have an Android application that shows an html view and I want to convert this view into binary data.

The main purpose is to print that html view via a bluetooth printer.

Is it something easy or should I look for another method ?

The only constrain I have is that the connection between the Android device and the printer MUST be direct (no google cloud print for example)

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you read this? https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html

Comment: "I want to convert this view into binary data" -- you may wish to explain in greater detail what this means. Pretty much everything involving computers is "binary data". "The main purpose is to print that html view via a bluetooth printer" -- contact the manufacturer of the Bluetooth printer and ask them how to print to their device from Android. On Android 4.4+, the printer might support Android's [printing framework](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html), but only the manufacturer can tell you that.

Comment: If you do that, you are going to print the html source code, not the well formated page.

Comment: @mittmemo : Thank you I will check if that solve my problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare : I did some research and I found out that I can print from a bluetooth printer just by sending "binary data" to it and I was afraid that convert my *.html file to binary will just print out the html code. This program is more like an experiment.

Comment: @StephaneMathis : Yes I thought about this that's why I was thinking of converting the intent to binary (but that sounds like a wierd way). If you have any idea that might do the job you're more than welcome :)